# Does the Azure IoT Hub support the CoAP protocol?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

Does the Azure IoT Hub support the CoAP protocol? I've only found external references like [this one](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/02/05/azure-iot-hub-general-availability.aspx) but nothing on their website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @Rajan Bhayana said, CoAP is not supported by Azure IoT Hub natively.

Maybe you can extend IoT Hub to provide support for CoAP protocol by:

> - Creating a field gateway with the [Azure IoT Gateway SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-gateway-sdk) that converts your custom protocol to one of the three protocols understood
>     by IoT Hub.
> - Customizing the [Azure IoT protocol gateway](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-protocol-gateway/blob/master/README.md), an open source component that runs in the cloud.

Answer (score 3):

Azure IoT Hub natively supports communication over the MQTT, AMQP, and HTTP protocols.

more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-protocol-gateway